# Best way to suppress errors when instantiating a Video.js player with a deliberately inactive source

Tags: error-handling, video.js

My client:

1. Sets up an `.m3u8` stream source for a live event in Wowza well ahead of it being live
2. Enters that source into his CMS and verifies
3. Then deactivates it in Wowza so that he only incurs stream charges when the event is live and a little bit beforehand
4. Leaves that deactivated `.m3u8` in his CMS to instantiate a Video.js player with a holding 'poster' image.

With `errorDisplay: false` set in the player options this works fine ahead of time in almost all respects, but it does generate **MediaError** messages in the Console due to the stream source itself returning a 404.

Although this error message is only visible to those hunting under the hood, is there a better way to set this up so that:

- A Video.js player is instantiated with poster image well ahead of time
- No Console error messages are generated prior to the stream being activated

?

---

I should add that my client doesn't really want to be changing the source in his CMS *when* he activates his Wowza stream. He wants his time sensitive admin to only have to be done in the Wowza control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace the Wowza with a regular webserver (NGINX, Apache, etc) with a static content, something like a promo saying "The stream will start this day, this hour, bla, bla"?

HLS is actually conceived to work off actual files on an actual webserver, so you could have a playlist.m3u8 with a bunch of .ts fragments, so the player would have what to actually load, without any Wowza there.

And when the time comes, stop the web server, start the Wowza, and from then on, users can see the live stream.

I don't know video.js, but if you're lucky, it might even refresh the playlist.m3u8 content from time to time, so the users that were seing the placeholder would begin to see the live stream automatically. Maybe, if you're lucky.